# How to use usb ports on a monitor for sound

Tags: usb, usb-audio

I have a monitor with 2 USB ports that I connect through HDMI to my laptop. How do I make a USB sound card work with those ports? My system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about generic computer hardware rather than Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB ports found on computer monitors are usually those of a
built-in USB hub: you would have to connect the monitor's hub to your
computer using a USB cable for it to work. Then any device, sound card
or anything else, should work as if it were connected directly to the
computer.